# Instance of struct inside class definition producing compiler error

Tags: c++

In a header file I have something to the effect of:

```
class MoveableObject
{
   public:

    static float Gravity;
    static float JumpSpeed;
    static float MoveSpeed;

    struct State;
    struct Derivative;

    State current;
    State previous;
};
```

When trying to compile I get the errors:

```
12:9: error: field 'current' has incomplete type
13:9: error: field 'previous' has incomplete type
```

It's probably a very basic mistake, but I'm stumped. Thanks.

Comment: show us the definition of `State` and make sure `State` is defined before it is used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forward declaration such as :

```
struct State;
struct Derivative;
```

Will only work for declarations if you manipulate pointers or references (because the compiler always knows the size of a pointer or a reference; however it can not guess the size of a user-defined type).

If you wish to keep your class as it is right now, you have to include the header file in which the structure State is defined.

Otherwise, switch to pointers!

Comment: Thank you! I just brought the definition from my .cpp file into the header.

Answer (score 0):

In the code in the question, `State` is a nested type inside `MovableObject`. To be able to create a member of type `State` inside `MovableObject` the definition of `State` must be inlined inside the definition of `MovableObject`:

```
class MovableObject {
public:
   struct State { ... };
   State current;
};
```